# SharePoint list form person field - auto fill with current user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, spservices, list-form

I have three person field in my list, in new list form I have to auto populated with current user's name **only for one field**. I wrote the following code. But this code auto populated with current user's name for all three user fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').text($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title",debug: false}));
</script>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your input field code? Have you set the same class name for all three input?

Comment: I didn't change anything in markup. Everything is same as default SharePoint.

Comment: We don't know what you got in the markup currently. We couldn't help you with the exact solution until you expose your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that you have set the same class name for all three elements like this,

```
<div class="ms-inputuserfield"></div>
<div class="ms-inputuserfield"></div>
<div class="ms-inputuserfield"></div>
```

when you query by it's class name $('div.ms-inputuserfield') will get the all three elements. So, when you change anything from here will update in all three elements.

---

**Solution 1:**

You can update to specific element based on it's index like this,

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').eq(index).text("your text")
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Providing the unique class name to get the exact element that you needed,

```
<div class="ms-inputuserfield current-user"></div>
<div class="ms-inputuserfield"></div>
<div class="ms-inputuserfield"></div>
```

And then in your javascript,

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield.current-user').text("your text")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because “$('div.ms-inputuserfield')” finds all attributes with “ms-inputuserfield” class.

Change it to the id of the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div#<id of the attribute>').text($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title",debug: false}));
});
</script>
```

Use F12 to get the id:

[image]

For example:

```
$('div#ctl00_m_g_b0ae3ac2_3b68_4235_9a78_7a3d521194e9_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv').text($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title",debug: false}));
```